# git pull request failed with "Permission denied (publickey)" error

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, git-pull

I have tried to pull my official repository to my local machine using

```
git pull git@github.com:x/x_project_management_app.git master
```

but it failed with error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have regenerated and added my system ssh-public key to my  github account and tried again, but I'm still facing same error. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you show output `ssh -T git@github.com` please.

Comment: did you genrate(https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) rsa  key(public) and add it to your github account

Comment: also check the files of `.ssh` folder has permissions ?

Comment: if no help but it's not `recommended` ( can you delete or move `.ssh` folder to somewhere and regenerate using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and update

Comment: i got same error for 'ssh -T git@github.com' also "Permission denied (publickey)."

Comment: @NIKHILKA your problems in public keys, check all twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure you `ssh` to ask for your private key. You should have something like :

```
Host github.com
Hostname github.com
User mvy
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
Compression yes
```

in the file called `.ssh\config` (it's in your home directory on *nix, or in `%userprofile%` on win).

When calling to ssh (or git if using a ssh adress), it should ask you for your keyfile password.